# Check if the second integer of a line in a file matches

Tags: shell-script, grep, pattern-matching

I have a file with the below format of entries.

```
$ cat mw.hosts
host23v0242 USER=wsadmin                                                  MOUNTPOINT=/web
server21v0243 USER=wsadmin                                                  MOUNTPOINT=/web
myser13v0418 USER=wladmin                                                  MOUNTPOINT=/web
whatever22v0419 USER=wladmin                                                  MOUNTPOINT=/web
....
....
```

I wish to grep  (list) all entries where the second integer from left is "3"

Thus in the above example the desired output is:

```
host23v0242 USER=wsadmin                                                  MOUNTPOINT=/web
myser13v0418 USER=wladmin                                                  MOUNTPOINT=/web
```

As you can see the second integer matches "3".

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep '^[^0-9]*[0-9]3' mw.hosts
```

or

```
grep '^[^[:digit:]]*[[:digit:]]3' mw.hosts
```

or (using perl-compatible regexps with GNU `grep -P`):

```
grep -P '^\D*\d3' mw.hosts
```

All of these will match any line which begins with zero-or-more non-digit characters, followed by any digit, followed by a `3`.

Comment: Amazing @cas. It works, The best i could try was -> `cat mw.hosts |sed -e 's/[^0-9 ]//g'  | cut -c2 | grep '3'`  which gives me all the lines having second integer as '3'; but had no idea how i could the entire line printed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use awk for this.

```
awk '/[0-9]3v/ { print }' mw.hosts
```

```bsh
awk '/[0-9]3v/ { print }' mw.hosts
host23v0242 USER=wsadmin                                                  MOUNTPOINT=/web
myser13v0418 USER=wladmin                                                  MOUNTPOINT=/web
```

Comment: That will also match entries where the third (or fourth, or fifth, or sixth, etc digit) digit is a 3, regardless of what the second digit is.

Comment: @cas Very true, but I am only answering the query with the data provided which provides the desired output..